# Delete files from directory that are not in Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

It's been awhile since I have done any Excel/VBA tricks.  I have a directory of over 1500 image files and a spreadsheet list of about 900 filenames (basically it's a directory of every image that's ever been used on a website and a spreadsheet of filenames that are currently used).  So I want to delete any files in the directory that are not found in the spreadsheet.  I have a toolkit of various file renaming macros but I can't quite come up with something that will work for this scenario. Thanks in advance...

UPDATE:
Ok, I found a round about solution using a file renaming macro.

```
Sub Test()
For N = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If Dir(Cells(N, 1)) <> "" Then
    Name Cells(N, 1) As Cells(N, 2)
End If
Next N
End Sub
```

I created an extra column in excel and filled it with a number series, then ran the macro.  Then I went to the directory and deleted all of the filenames that were not renamed to a number.  Then I swapped column 1 and column 2 in my spreadsheet and ran the macro again to rename them back to their original filename.  I posted this in case anyone else finds this macro useful someday.  But if anyone has a more direct solution to my problem I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would

- use `Dir()` to list all the files in the directory into a second column of Excel
- use `For Each` to examine each cell in this new column of file names
- within the For..Each use Excel's `MATCH` function to check if the file exists in the existing column
- use `Kill` to delete the files
- `Delete` these two columns when complete.

I might store a value of "DELETE" in a third column and do the deletions separately afterwards. (Or, more usefully, just copy the name of the file to delete to this third column.)

I am reluctant to provide code though until you have made an attempt yourself.

**Added** Actually, I would probably use COUNTIF() in the third column and use this as the basis to perform file deletions; but there are always a number of approaches to take ;)

Comment: Thanks, and I understand.  I just updated my question with a macro that I successfully used.  I wanted to include an else clause in my macro that would delete the remaining filenames but couldn't quite get it to work.  I will try implementing your algorithm and save it for future use.